# I cant get this widget to work in react. It is embedded with <script>

Tags: reactjs, widget

I have tried the below option as well as adding the script to the HTML file. The below method shows in the console after loading the page but nothing is showing up on the page.

THis is the code from the widget.

```
      -`<div id='ss-custom-reviews-widget-root'></div>
      -<script
      -id='ss-custom-reviews-widget-script'
      -src='https://secret;)'
      -ss-custom-reviews-widget-api-key='secret;)'
      -widget-key='secret;)'
      -type='text/javascript'>
      -</script>`
```

This is the code I tried

```
      -`const data = `

      -<div id='ss-custom-reviews-widget-root'></div>
      -<script
      -id='ss-custom-reviews-widget-script'
      -src='https://secret;)'
      -ss-custom-reviews-widget-api-key='secret;)'
      -widget-key='secret;)'
      -type='text/javascript'>
      -</script>`

     -`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{\__html: data}}/>`
```

thank you for any help!

Comment: I stumbled on an answer randomly and since I building the site myself I added an npm package and made it work. The code is below                                                                  
 npm install react-helmet
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://" ss-custom-reviews-widget-api-key="" widget-key="" type="text/javascript" />
      </Helmet>
      <div id="ss-custom-reviews-widget-root" />
    </div>
  );
}